# JS Create A Date Object from value passed via AJAX Call

Tags: javascript

I have a Python script that returns me a calculated date time in XML format like below:

```
<prev><date>2012,07,16</date><time>22:00:00</time></prev>
```

Though I can change the format but my issue is that when I try creating a JS date object using the value returned - I get 'Invalid date':

```
$.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url:  "/cgi-bin/prev_hour.py",
        success: function(xml)
        {
                pdate = $(xml).find('date').text();
                ptime = $(xml).find('time').text();
                //alert prints correct date time ex 2012-07-16 22:00:00
        },
        error:function(xhr,err,html)
        {
                alert("Failed\nreadyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status + "\nresponseText: "+xhr.responseText);
        }

var max_date = new Date("'" + pdate + ptime + "'");
alert(max_date);
```

I tried a couple of possibilities like Python script returning in various format:

```
<prev><date>2012/07/16 </date><time>22:00:00</time></prev>
<prev><date>2012,07,16 </date><time>22,00,00</time></prev>
```

But still I get invalid date when trying to create a JS date object?

Please let me know the correct way to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the extra set of quotes in your date string, and you will need a space between the date and time components, try:

```
new Date(pdate + " " + ptime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using amazing lib for dates called [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment("2012/07/16 22:00:00")
```

from there you can achieve everything with dates.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var max_date = new Date("'" + pdate + ptime + "'");
```

Should be:

```
var max_date = new Date(pdate + ' ' + ptime);
```

Next time you run into such issues put an alert on the value you are sending to the function and see what it looks like.